# Mongify Ubuntu 14.04 installing error

Tags: mongodb, postgresql, ubuntu-14.04, database-migration, mongify

I am trying to install mongify in my Ubuntu 14 box, but its throwing some error:

```
gem install mongify

ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Gem::DependencyError)
Unable to resolve dependencies: mongify requires bson (>= 1.10.2); bson_ext requires bson (~> 1.12.5); mongo requires bson (~> 4.0)
```

I already have installed mongo db in my machine, which is working fine. Is there a seperate package needed to be installed for BSON?

Comment: Exact same problem; exact same error message. Also manually built and installed libbson which did not help.

Comment: (Just successfully installed this locally on an up-to-date installation of OS X)

Comment: Looks like Ubuntu 14.04  only has the issue

Comment: @axlotl Please verify the solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Figured it out, So ubuntu 14 has an inbuilt ruby, which is a lower version. We need a higher version of that. So what we have to do is create an virenv with the higher version.

1.)Install ruby. Follow the steps in this link
https://gorails.com/setup/ubuntu/14.04 (Install using rvm method)

2.) Install Bundler.
gem install bundler

3.) Install mongify
gem install mongify